# Workaround for error when creating a correlation matrix of a huge matrix?

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix of size 55422 x 888, and so the rcorr function is producing this error:

```
M1<-matrix(rnorm(36),nrow=55422, ncol=888)

cor <- rcorr(t(M1), type = "pearson")
```

Error in double(p * p) : vector size cannot be NA
In addition: Warning message:
In p * p : NAs produced by integer overflow

Is there anything I can do to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't a complete/working solution, but will give you an idea of some of the issues.

Your correlation matrix will contain `n*(n-1)/2` = 1535771331 unique elements. If each correlation takes one millisecond to compute, computing the correlation matrix will take `(n^2-n)/2/(1e6*3600)` = 0.42 hours and require `(n^2-n)/2*8/(2^30)` = 11.4 Gb of storage. These requirements are not impossible if you have a lot of RAM and time ...

In fact it's a little bit worse than this, since `rcorr` returns its results as a symmetric matrix (i.e., not taking advantage of the symmetry), and returns the `n` and `P` matrices as well, so the storage requirement will be approximately 5 times as great as stated above (double for the full matrix, x 2.5 because we have two double-precision and one integer matrix).

Getting to your specific question, the [section on long vectors in the R internals manual](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html#Long-vectors) discusses the maximum sizes of objects in R. The 'standard' limitation is that the total number of elements of the matrix should be less than 2^31 (`(n^2-n)/2/(2^31-1)` = 0.72), but the redundancy in the matrix gets you in trouble (as would the storage of the correlation, p-values, *and* the sample sizes).

If you still want to go ahead, here is an implementation by A.N. Spiess, copied from [here](http://www.dr-spiess.de/scripts/bigcor.r), that breaks the problem into blocks and stores the results in a disk-backed array (i.e., not in RAM).  This won't get you the p-values (and it's still not clear what you're going to do with all those values ...), but it works at least up to 40,000 columns (takes about a minute).

However, it seems to crap out on your actual problem size (888 x 55242) with a too-large length. I'd have to look more closely and see if there is a limitation here we can get around ... It seems that we are actually still limited by the matrix dimensions ... (maximum matrix dimension is `sqrt(2^31-1)` approx. 46341 ... With more work, we could still do the block-diagonal thing and split this into several components ...

```r
set.seed(101)
nc <- 55422
nr <- 888
d <- matrix(rnorm(nr*nc), ncol = nc)
t1 <- system.time(b1 <- bigcor(d))
```

```r
bigcor <- function(
x,
y = NULL,
fun = c("cor", "cov"),
size = 2000,
verbose = TRUE,
...)
{
  if (!require("ff")) stop("please install the ff package")
  fun <- match.arg(fun)
  if (fun == "cor") FUN <- cor else FUN <- cov
  if (fun == "cor") STR <- "Correlation" else STR <- "Covariance"
  if (!is.null(y) & NROW(x) != NROW(y)) stop("'x' and 'y' must have compatible dimensions!")

  NCOL <- ncol(x)
  if (!is.null(y)) YCOL <- NCOL(y)

  ## calculate remainder, largest 'size'-divisible integer and block size
  REST <- NCOL %% size
  LARGE <- NCOL - REST
  NBLOCKS <- NCOL %/% size

  ## preallocate square matrix of dimension
  ## ncol(x) in 'ff' single format
  if (is.null(y)) resMAT <- ff(vmode = "double", dim = c(NCOL, NCOL))
  else resMAT <- ff(vmode = "double", dim = c(NCOL, YCOL))

  ## split column numbers into 'nblocks' groups + remaining block
  GROUP <- rep(1:NBLOCKS, each = size)
  if (REST > 0) GROUP <- c(GROUP, rep(NBLOCKS + 1, REST))
  SPLIT <- split(1:NCOL, GROUP)

  ## create all unique combinations of blocks
  COMBS <- expand.grid(1:length(SPLIT), 1:length(SPLIT))
  COMBS <- t(apply(COMBS, 1, sort))
  COMBS <- unique(COMBS)
  if (!is.null(y)) COMBS <- cbind(1:length(SPLIT), rep(1, length(SPLIT)))

  ## initiate time counter
  timeINIT <- proc.time()

  ## iterate through each block combination, calculate correlation matrix
  ## between blocks and store them in the preallocated matrix on both
  ## symmetric sides of the diagonal
  for (i in 1:nrow(COMBS)) {
    COMB <- COMBS[i, ]
    G1 <- SPLIT[[COMB[1]]]
    G2 <- SPLIT[[COMB[2]]]

    ## if y = NULL
    if (is.null(y)) {
      if (verbose) cat(sprintf("#%d: %s of Block %s and Block %s (%s x %s) ... ", i, STR,  COMB[1],
                               COMB[2], length(G1),  length(G2)))
      RES <- FUN(x[, G1], x[, G2], ...)
      resMAT[G1, G2] <- RES
      resMAT[G2, G1] <- t(RES)
    } else ## if y = smaller matrix or vector
    {
      if (verbose) cat(sprintf("#%d: %s of Block %s and 'y' (%s x %s) ... ", i, STR,  COMB[1],
                               length(G1),  YCOL))
      RES <- FUN(x[, G1], y, ...)
      resMAT[G1, ] <- RES
    }

    if (verbose) {
      timeNOW <- proc.time() - timeINIT
      cat(timeNOW[3], "s\n")
    }

    gc()
  }

  return(resMAT)
}
```